# Press button device for PC keyboard space key simulation

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, input-device

I am looking for a commercial input device(Button ) , which can interface with PC,preferably via USB, and serve as a substitute for a standard PC keyboard space bar press.

Comment: Which operating system? Are there any other restrictions on this device? You can use an XBox 360 controller on Windows and map one of the (many) buttons to the space bar "out of the box".

Comment: Must work on windows and preferably on Mac.It must have a single button only.Thanks .

Comment: Don't understand why down vote this question...

Comment: Maybe [this project](http://www.frank-zhao.com/cache/usbggbutton.php) is of interest to you.

Comment: The project it was based off was what i was thinking of when i suggested the teensy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing i can think of to a universal keyboard emulator is a presentation remote, but the emulate page up and down, iirc.If you're willing to put a little elbow grease into it (and solder fumes), there's options.

You could use a [teensy](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/) - a microcontroller thats often used for custom keyboards and keyboard emulation- with the appropriate button connected to the pins [One of the examples](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/usb_keyboard.html) covers the necessary hardware and firmware. Add a nice case and you're golden. This will work anywhere a keyboard would with no additional drivers needed.

You could also, presumably use a programmable mouse, and set one or more of the keys to spacebar only, though this is clunky.

Finally, if you can find one the [griffin powermate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griffin_PowerMate) might be an option - apparently its a programmable knob.

Comment: Your link is fine for a home usage or prototyping .I need a user ready solution.Something I can plug into USB and may be some config interface in the user PC (for key mapping) and that is it.Thanks anyways.

Comment: You never mentioned the config interface - the griffin powermate may be an option, as would programmable mice.

Comment: It is not must if the device can target a space press automatically .